# jquery ui dialog how to detect loss of focus

Tags: jquery-ui, dialog, focus, jquery-ui-dialog, lost-focus

I have been searching for quite some time without success. I want to detect when a particular jquery ui dialog has lost focus.
I know I can detect when it gains focus like so:

```
focus: function(event, ui) { console.log('focus in: '+this.id); }
```

However the focusout event does not get triggered in any way I've tried:

```
focusout: function(event, ui) { console.log('focus out: '+this.id);}
```

This is my (PHP echo'ed) code:

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
$(\"".$element."\").click(function(e){
    $(\"#".$divname."\").load('".$url."').dialog({
    title: '".$title."',
    modal:".$modal.", 
    resizable: true, 
    width:'".$width."', 
    height:'".$height."', 
    show: 'clip',
    hide: 'clip',
    open: function(event, ui) {\$(\".ui-widget-overlay\").css({'background-image': 'url(\"../css/stripe_small.png\")','background-repeat':'repeat', 'opacity':'0.8'})},
    minimize: '#toolbar',
    focus: function(event, ui) { console.log('focus in: '+this.id); },
    focusout: function(event, ui) { console.log('focus out: '+this.id);}});
    });
</script>
<div id=\"".$divname."\"></div>";
```

Everything works allright, apart from the focus out detection. Is there a way to do this, or do I have to iterate all window elements to find out which has the focus ?

EDIT: Alternatively, I would like to know if I can find which UI Dialog is the one at the front.

Comment: Are you setting modal to true? If so you can bind to clicks on the `<div class="ui-widget-overlay ui-front"></div>` that gets created behind the dialog.

Comment: @j08691 No, unfortunately none of them is set to modal. I am trying to detect which dialog is front and change the appearance of the ones at the back.

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody has answered I will give a brief answer to what I have come up with.
jQuery's **blur** and **focusout** do not seem to trigger for my dialogs:

When trying to listen for events of a dialog widget:

```
$(".ui-dialog.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-corner-all.ui-draggable.ui-resizable").blur(function({ //NOP });
```

When trying to listen for events of the divname used for a dialog:

```
$("#divname").blur( function({ //NOP });
```

Do not get triggered.
Weirdly enough, **focusin** does work:

```
$("#divname").focusin( function({ console.log('focused in'); });
```

A hackish solution (which may be a bit heavy if there are many ui-dialogs on the page as it so happens in my case, but which works nonetheless, is to listen for click events on ui-dialogs:

```
$(".ui-dialog.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-corner-all.ui-draggable.ui-resizable").live('click',function(){
  $(this).addClass('ui-active').removeClass('ui-inactive');
});
```

What this does it the exact opposite: instead of trying to detect a dialog losing focus, onclick I iterate all dialogs. The one with the highest ZIndex is at the top, the rest are not (and thus have lost focus):

```
var topZindex = 0;
$(".ui-dialog.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-corner-all.ui-draggable.ui-resizable").each( function( ){
  var thisZindex = parseInt($(this).css('zIndex'), 10);
  if ( thisZindex > topZindex ) topZindex = thisZindex;
});
```

It would be really nice if somehow a callback would trigger when the entire ui-dialog lost focus, but I can't seem to find another solution on the web, and I cannot get blur or focusout to trigger.